# Vlans On Pfsense Router/Firewall

Tags: networking, pfsense

I am trying to configure VLANs on my pfsense router however there is a  question that puzzles me at the moment.

Question: When I create a VLAN what happens to my default LAN (Lan on the Lan port of my NIC)?Will it be a connection to the switch as a trunk port or should I use another port on the NIC for VLANs and use my default lan as is?

Example: Default lan is 192.168.1.x and vlan 10 is 192.168.2.x

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a switch with a single link (a trunk), tags are added to Ethernet frames to identify the VLAN they belong to. You need a switch and NIC that support the IEEE 802.1q standard. Several tagged VLANs could be bound to a single port so you don't need another one.